# Multiple image compression without quality loss before upload

Tags: jquery, ajax, razor, model-view-controller

I need to upload multiple images to server but before uploading they must be compressed at client side without quality loss (using jQuery).

Is there any way to get the width and height of each image?

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#Upload").click(function() {
            var formData = new FormData();
            var image = new Image();
            var totalFiles = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files.length;

            for (var i = 0; i < totalFiles; i++) {
                var file = document.getElementById("fileUpload").files[i];
                formData.append("fileUpload", file);
            }

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '/Ajaximage/Upload',
                data: formData,

                dataType: 'json',
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                success: function(response) {
                    //alert('succes!!');
                },
                error: function(error) {
                    //alert("Failed");
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: The `ajax` request that uploads the image resides on the server doesn't it? Either the user does the lossless compression on it's own computer or you let the upload script do it.

Comment: Please do not add library or language names in title. They are not required because they are part of the tag list. Also, format the code better (like proper indentations, cutting out unnecessary line breaks etc) before posting. Better formatted code helps readability. I have reworded the content a bit to better explain your question. Coming to the code, have you tried anything specific for compressing the image? Did it give you any errors? If yes, please include the error message in question.

Answer (score 0):

after you receive the file at the web service you are calling using ajax. typecast it into a System.Drawing.Image object. you can get the image height and width using Height and Width properties if System.Drawing.Image Object.

By compression i think you mean resizing the image
Try this function

```
  public  System.Drawing.Image resizeImage(System.Drawing.Image imgToResize,int Width,int Height)
  {



         int sourceWidth = imgToResize.Width;
        int sourceHeight = imgToResize.Height;

        float nPercent = 0;
        float nPercentW = 0;
        float nPercentH = 0;

        nPercentW = ((float)Width / (float)sourceWidth);
        nPercentH = ((float)Height / (float)sourceHeight);

        if (nPercentH < nPercentW)
            nPercent = nPercentH;
        else
            nPercent = nPercentW;

        int destWidth = (int)(sourceWidth * nPercent);
        int destHeight = (int)(sourceHeight * nPercent);

        Bitmap b = new Bitmap(destWidth, destHeight);
        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((System.Drawing.Image)b);
        g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

        g.DrawImage(imgToResize, 0, 0, destWidth, destHeight);
        g.Dispose();

        return (System.Drawing.Image)b;
    }
```

there will be slight quality loss but aspect ration will be maintained